# how to output the result of a nested loop using Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

I have a function with 3 arguments. I want to calculate that function and output the result for each of the argument combinations.

I have defined my function `F(A,B,C)`, and for now we can assume its output is a single value `f(A,B,C)`.

I then run a nested loop:

```
for A in range(1,2):
    for B in range(4,5):
        for C in range(7,8,9):
            F(A,B,C)
```

But it overrides. What I want to get is a dataframe like this:

```
A   B   C   Output
1   4   7   f(1,4,7)
1   4   8   f(1,4,8)
1   4   9   f(1,4,9)
1   5   7   f(1,5,7)
1   5   8   f(1,5,8)
1   5   9   f(1,5,9)
2   4   7   f(2,4,7)
2   4   8   f(2,4,8)
2   4   9   f(2,4,9)
2   5   7   f(2,5,7)
2   5   8   f(2,5,8)
2   5   9   f(2,5,9)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`range(x,y)` does not include the value y

For example `range(1,3)` contains the numbers `[1,2]` **NOT**  `[1,2,3]`

```
for A in range(1,3):
    for B in range(4,6):
        for C in range(7,10):
            print(A,B,C)
```

output:

```
1 4 7
1 4 8
1 4 9
1 5 7
1 5 8
1 5 9
2 4 7
2 4 8
2 4 9
2 5 7
2 5 8
2 5 9
```

Here's what your ranges were doing

- `range(1,2)` --> [1]
- `range(4,5)` --> [4]
- `range(7,8,9)` --> [7] (This one is even nastier because the third argument is the step value)

As you can see you are just creating 3 ranges with only one item, so when you loop through it never repeats like you want because each range only has one value

That's why your program outputs (1,4,7) then terminates if you change F to print. In my example I **increased the second argument of each range by 1** to get the result that you desired.

**Making it a dataframe:**

```
listData = []
for A in range(1, 3):
    for B in range(4, 6):
        for C in range(7, 10):
            listData.append([A,B,C, A+B+C]) #I just used A+B+C instead of the func f

df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B", "C", "Output"], data = listData)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, it was a silly mistake. In the actual case I'm using `[val1, val2, val3]` because it is not a continuous list. I can print the output by `print(A,B,C,F(A,B,C))`, but don't know how to make it a dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem, I've edited my answer now to show it being converted to a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use the [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
import pandas
# Assumes you know the inputs
A = [1, 2]
B = [4, 5]
C = [7, 8, 9]
# args = list(itertools.product(A, B, C))
args = [list(x) for x in itertools.product(A, B, C)]

def my_func(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3
```

As you can see the code above prevents you from having to use nested loops.

You can now do things like:

```
for arg in args:
    arg.append(my_func(*arg))
df = pandas.DataFrame(args, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'SUM'])
```

Comment: you could also do `[x + (my_func(*x),) for ...]` to get rid of the need to then loop over it again or cast each element to a list.